# Sprite Kit - Changing SKShapeNode's anchor point doesn't change SKPhysicalBody position

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I changed the anchor point of my SKSpriteNode, but it seems that the SKPhysicalBody is not correct.

Without setting the anchor point of my sprite, it would appear out of the screen by a little, using anchor point fixed this problem.
But after setting the anchor point, the physical body is still at the previous location (before changing the anchor point)

```
func addGround() {
    let gSize = CGSizeMake(self.size.width/4*3, 120);
    let ground = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.brownColor(), size: gSize);
    ground.name = gName;

    ground.anchorPoint = CGPointZero
    ground.position = CGPointMake(0, 0);

    ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: ground.size);
    ground.physicsBody.restitution = 0.0;
    ground.physicsBody.friction = 0.0;
    ground.physicsBody.angularDamping = 0.0;
    ground.physicsBody.linearDamping = 0.0;
    ground.physicsBody.allowsRotation = false;
    ground.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true; //accurate collision
    ground.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = false;
    ground.physicsBody.dynamic = false;
    ground.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = gBitmask;
    ground.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = pBitmask;
}
```

The box is drawn correctly, but enabling `skView.showPhysics` showed me that the physical body is still not correct.

[image]
The left side is the physics body for the box seen in the middle of the screen....
The physics body is diagonally down towards the left side.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? It would help make what's happening more clear.

Comment: Set your anchor point before setting your ground.position

Comment: @0x7fffffff a screenshot has been added.

Comment: @meisenman I notice i copied a old version of my code here. I have updated it with anchor point set before the position

Comment: To make a ground you can just set the ground.position=CGPointMake(self.size.x/2,60);//specific to your ground. Also, remove the anchor point.

Comment: @meisenman self.size has no member named x, and what if I need to put my ground at 0,0?

Answer (score 2):

The anchorPoint is the position of the texture relative to the node's position. In other words, changing the anchorPoint changes where the texture is drawn relative to the sprite's position.

As such, the physics body shape is unaffected by changes to the anchorPoint since the node's position remains unaffected.

Note that on 4" iPhones your ground body's size would be 426x120 extending from the bottom left corner of the screen (assuming the scene's position is 0,0).

Also note that there is a small threshold around collision shapes which prevent them from lining up exactly, there may be a small gap if you use the exact same size as the images. Therefore you may need to make the shapes a little bit smaller.